# VueJS Instafeed template ignored on specific images

Tags: javascript, vue.js, instafeedjs

absolute beginner at using Vue here. I've been asked to convert a PHP site to VueJS and I have enjoyed the chance to start learning a JS framework. However - I'm having a single strange issue.

One of my Vue components is a Gallery page, which pulls thumbnails from an instagram account. This is done using "instafeed.js". This is working very nicely except that, my template is not applied to a couple of the images for some reason.

Gallery.vue :

```
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="instafeed"></div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import $ from 'jquery'
import Instafeed from 'instafeed'

var userFeed = new Instafeed({
  get: 'user',
  userId: 'USER-ID',
  accessToken: 'ACCESS-TOKEN',
  limit: 25,
  imageTemplate: '<a href="{{link}}" target="_blank" id="{{id}}"><img src="{{image}}" /></a>',
  onAfter: function () {
    var images = $('#instafeed').find('a')
    $.each(images, function (index, image) {
      var delay = (index * 75) + 'ms'
      $(image).css('-webkit-animation-delay', delay)
      $(image).css('-moz-animation-delay', delay)
      $(image).css('-ms-animation-delay', delay)
      $(image).css('-o-animation-delay', delay)
      $(image).css('animation-delay', delay)
      $(image).addClass('animated flipInX')
    })
  }
})
userFeed.run()
```

This will apply the template to each image returned. You can see I have a limit of 21 images. Each image will look like this:

```
<a href="INSTAGRAM-POST-LINK" target="_blank" id="ID" class="animated flipInX" style="animation-delay: 0ms;">
    <img src="IMG-LINK-HERE"/>
</a>
```

However, for some reason, images 4, 6, 8 12, 16, 19, 21 are being loaded without the anchor tag.

```
<img src="IMG-LINK-HERE"/>
```

I have no idea what could be causing this, and this doesn't occur on the PHP version of the site. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: This most likely won't answer your question, but I'd recommend to stop using Jquery to alter the DOM, normally frameworks like VueJs don't work right when you edit the DOM yourself

Comment: I've never used this Instafeed lib, but my (wild) guess for your issue is that the `link` or `id` properties is somehow missing then it doesn't render properly. And as George said, you shouldn't mess around DOM manually when using Vue.js (and others), instead, you could define CSS for the common class and see if the Instafeed lib can provide the `index`, which you would "vue bind" to the style property

Comment: @George @GriffoGoes It seems that the issue persists if I remove jquery entirely `// import $ from 'jquery'`, move the css to a class and then inline `class="ig-image animated flipInX"` on the template. It seems to me that the issue occurs before the jquery.